# why query working on phpmyadmin but not in php page

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and I have a problem in my code. I have two tables:

```
seeker

seeker_nic | username
-----------+----------
111        | ali
222        | umer
333        | raza

bloodrequest

id | seeker_nic | requireddate
---+------------+--------------
1  | 111        | 2012/9/9
2  | 222        | 2012/5/8
3  | 111        | 2012/10/11
4  | 111        | 2012/11/12
5  | 222        | 2012/7/9
6  | 333        | 2012/4/4
```

Now I want to list users one time with maximum date like..

```
s.no | username | requireddate
-----+----------+--------------
1    | ali      | 2012/11/12
2    | umer     | 2012/7/9
3    | raza     | 2012/4/4
```

I am using this query...

```
select seeker.username, max(bloodrequest.requireddate)
from seeker
join bloodrequest on seeker.seeker_nic=bloodrequest.seeker_nic
group by seeker.username
```

This query works in phpMyAdmin, it shows the result that I wanted.  But when I run this query in PHP an error occured on requireddate column:

`"Undefined index: requireddate in C:\wamp\www\list.php on line 64"`

Line 64 is:

`<td><?php echo $rec['requireddate']; ?></td>`

Can anyone please tell me where is the problem

Comment: Please include your php code that is calling your mysql query / populating your $rec array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select seeker.username, max(bloodrequest.requireddate) as requireddate
from seeker
join bloodrequest on seeker.seeker_nic=bloodrequest.seeker_nic
group by seeker.username
```

should work then. you need to give the column the name you want.

Comment: this is correct, but for an explanation: `max(bloodrequest.requireddate)` would be the column name as that is what you are selecting. by using `as requireddate`, you are re-naming that to `requireddate` so it will be `$rec['requireddate']` when you are in php.

Comment: OMG it workeddd.. thank youu sooooooo muchhh !!!! :) :) u have solved my problem .. thnx once again..:)

Comment: JonathanKuhn thanks for the addition. @mahan good to hear that :)

Comment: @maham If an answer was provided, don't forget to mark it as the answer.